# Reputation change text unreadable when bounty received

Tags: bug, design

The reputation point box is unreadable when a bounty is involved. Perhaps make the text white inside this box...?

[image: screenshot of unreadable text]

Comment: ew, didn't find that via searching...

Comment: as an aside, can a question previously asked but lacking any answers still be considered a duplicate?

Comment: Yes. The "must have answers" rule for duplicates doesn't apply on Meta.